# Change the number of lines scrolled in NSScrollView/NSTextView for keyboard arrows?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsscrollview

I can change the amount `NSScrollView` scrolls by when a user clicks on the arrows under the scroll bar, but how do I change the amount the document scrolls by when the user uses the keyboard? (i.e. user is moving line-by-line through the text with the keyboard down arrow, or is editing a region close to the bottom of the visible rect).

I'm trying to stop it from scrolling by what seems to be 50% of the visible rect, and make it scroll by just the height of a single line.  Can't find the method to set this behaviour.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a setting to do this. However, you could intercept the key strokes in an appropriate NSResponder method and look for an arrow key and if scrolling is necessary, scroll by the amount you want and then let the normal responder chain handle the key press.